# Кластер с двумя близкими метками не раскрывается Yandex Map API 2.1

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api, кластеризация

[image: Кластеризатор без опции minClusterSize]

Как видно, проблема в том что две близкие метки не раскрываются (как ожидается от клика на кластер). При это зум достиг максимума.

[image: Кластеризатор с заданием {minClusterSize: 3}]

Установка опции на количество точек для создания кластера {minClusterSize: 3} показывает, что метки могут отображаться отдельно.

Задание малого размера в опциях кластеризатора {gridSize: 5} также не решает проблему с такими близкими метками (хотя отдельные проблемные кластеры начинают раскрываться), но эта опция загрязняет карту множеством отдельных меток.

Использую такой код для создания кластера:

```
const clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
    clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 2,
    hasBalloon: false,
    // minClusterSize: 3,
    // gridSize: 5,
});

clusterer.createCluster = function (center, geoObjects) {
    // Создаем метку-кластер с помощью стандартной реализации метода.
    var clusterPlacemark = ymaps.Clusterer.prototype.createCluster.call(this, center, geoObjects),
        geoObjectsLength = clusterPlacemark.getGeoObjects().length;
    let chartRadius = 24, coreRadius = 16;
    
    // Радиус кластера зависит от числа объеденных меток
    if (geoObjectsLength < 10) {
        chartRadius = 21;
        coreRadius = 14;
    }
    clusterPlacemark.options.set({
        clusterIconPieChartRadius: chartRadius,
        clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: coreRadius,
    });
    return clusterPlacemark;
};

clusterer.add(mapsGeoObjects);
maps.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
maps.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds());
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать адекватное значение размера ячейки кластеризации. Например, 64. Если метки не будут разделяться, соберите полный пример на jsbin.com или в иной песочнице так, чтобы ситуация была воспроизводима.